# How to disable Play store from updating itself?

Tags: google-play-store, application-autoupdate

I don't quite like the new design of the play store, and wish to stay with version 3 of it.

Is it possible (by root if needed, and I think it is needed) to disable it from auto-updating?

Will I even miss anything from the new versions ?

Comment: In the past, there was a `MarketUpdater.apk` which did this. If you can find that app and disable it, it might keep updates away -- not sure, I didn't test. And yes, the latest version is horrible: hard to hit the "update" button, and then this "update on WiFi -- yes, later" missing the "never" option...

Comment: it's not just that. they have a new style which shows everything so large as if i have horrible eyes sight, and they still don't allow anonymous comments on the play store (what if i don't want a google+ account, or i have one but don't want to use it there ? ) .

Answer (score 1):

For now, the only solution I've come up with is to use the really old 2.3.6 version of the market app.

This is the only one that doesn't auto-update itself.

In order to install it, you have to uninstall the play store, install it, and convert it to a system app.

If you wish, you can use titanium backup to backup the old version for later use.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to found out the Play Store update IP address and have it blocked using the
iptables tool (using busybox)

Comment: won't i mean that i won't be able to install/update apps from the play store? besides, how can i figure out what are the IPs being used by another app? is it even possible?

Comment: It depends, if the same IP address is used for both downloading apps and checking for google play updates, it'll be a problem.

You get the IP address by doing one of the following:
1) Decompile the google play apk, search for the methods that responsible for the store update, look if there is a url that the app check with and then use nslookup to check what's the domain IP address.
2)Use tcpdump on your device and wait for the google play to check for update. After you are sure it updated, you can stop the tcpdump and start researching it on wireshark.
Both are not so simple, it's up to you:)

Comment: that's reverse engineering. such a thing might broke up some day. anyway, this is quite an interesting tip, but i think that i will just leave this question, as it seems google made a good job annoying me with bad updates.

Comment: Any results? Did anybody find the IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've been able to do it is with [Lucky Patcher](https://www.luckypatchers.com/download/). It has a "custom patch" for the play store that disables the self updating. It may not work with all versions but it worked for me running 4.9.13

Comment: Could you provide the link to the app?

Comment: Sure :   http://luckypatcher.net/

Answer (score -1):

Here is how you do it:

- Open Play Store
- Tap the top left corner to open the menu
- Select "Settings"
- Under "General" there is an "Auto-Update" with 3 options

Comment: That setting refers to the apps installed by the Play store not the store itself.