# How do I disable Google Play Store apps such that it will not enable itself without my permission

Tags: 7.0-nougat, 7.1-nougat

When I restart the Android 7 device phone, which is not rooted, the Google Play Store apps must not run again unless I implicitly enable it to run again. (Currently, the disable button for this app is disabled, which cause me not able to disable the app.)

Also, another reason for disable Google Play Store app is that it keep download at the background without user permission and at the wrong time, causing the app that I am using not able to use the whole bandwidth.

Also, there is no options in the Google Play Store app for me to set the timing when to do update. (Google need to learn from Microsoft Windows Update scheduler for this feature!)

From my findings, I need to connect to a PC and using the ADB as follows:

```
adb devices
adb shell
cmd approps set <package_name> RUN_IN_BACKGROUND ignore
```

However, it seems not working for those apps from Google (such as Google Play Store apps)!

Please do not tell me to install BackgroundRestrictor (https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.pavelsikun.runinbackgroundpermissionsetter/) as it can only be used on Android 7 device phone that is rooted.

Also, please do not tell me to root my phone.

Lastly, please do not say that this question is a duplicate of that question - [How to disable Play store from updating itself?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45410/how-to-disable-play-store-from-updating-itself) as that question is almost 6 years old and may not apply to Android 7 device phones.

Comment: It's not possible. Play Store is immune to such means that work for other apps. It is deeply integrated with OS. AFAIK rooted means also don't work

Comment: Installing a firewall then blocking `Media Storage`, `Download Manager`, `Downloads`, `Google Play Services` and `Google Play Store` from accessing the internet is one possibility. However, other apps not from Google may require `Media Storage`, `Download Manager` and `Downloads` when they want to download files, plus you will not be able to update the apps if automatically `Google Play Store` is the market you used

Comment: Try the commands `pm disable com.android.vending` or `pm hide com.android.vending`